# SQL Server - Implicit Join vs Explicit different results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was under the impression that

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.AID AND b.SomeString <> 'ABC'
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM Table a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.AID
WHERE b.AID IS NULL OR b.SomeString <> 'ABC'
```

would bare the same results.

Unfortunately in my case they are not :-(

Any reason why they might not be?

Comment: Because they are different queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Table A**

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

**Table B**

```
+-----+-----------------+
| AID |   SomeString    |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 | SomeOtherString |
|   2 | ABC             |
+-----+-----------------+
```

---

### Query 1

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableA a
       LEFT JOIN TableB b
         ON a.ID = b.AID
            AND b.SomeString <> 'ABC'
```

This joins each row from `A` with every row from `B` matching `a.ID = b.AID AND b.SomeString <> 'ABC'`. If there were zero rows matching the row from A it is preserved in the result with `NULL` for the columns in table `B` (as happens for Id=2 below - the single row matching the id didn't meet the second condition and Id=3 where there was not even a row matching the id)

```
+----+------+-----------------+
| ID | AID  |   SomeString    |
+----+------+-----------------+
|  1 | 1    | SomeOtherString |
|  2 | NULL | NULL            |
|  3 | NULL | NULL            |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

### Query 1.5

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.AID
```

This changes the semantics slightly because now to be considered a match only the `id` predicate needs to be met not the string condition. The rows in A with ids 2 and 3 match rows in B under this new matching condition and only id=3 was added back in by the outer join.

```
+----+------+-----------------+
| ID | AID  |   SomeString    |
+----+------+-----------------+
|  1 | 1    | SomeOtherString |
|  2 | 2    | ABC             |
|  3 | NULL | NULL            |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

### Query 2

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableA a
       LEFT JOIN TableB b
         ON a.ID = b.AID
WHERE  b.AID IS NULL
        OR b.SomeString <> 'ABC'
```

This runs the  `WHERE  b.AID IS NULL OR b.SomeString <> 'ABC` predicate on the rows shown in the Query 1.5 results. Leaving you with two rows. The row preserved by the outer join is one of them.

```
+----+------+-----------------+
| ID | AID  |   SomeString    |
+----+------+-----------------+
|  1 | 1    | SomeOtherString |
|  3 | NULL | NULL            |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the time and an excellent answer!!! Can't believe how stupid I was before reading this :-D sorry haha

Answer (score 3):

Because of NULL logic.

In the first query, you get all rows in A, joined on B only if the keys match **and** b.SomeString does not equal ABC. If b.SomeString is null, as it will be if the key is not found, you get `…and NULL is not equal to ABC`. As per the the rules of NULL comparison, comparing NULL with anything "fails", e.g. `NULL <> ‘ABC’` equates to false. Net result: if the ID is not found, b.SomeString is NULL, and the row gets discarded from the returned set.

In the second query, you get all rows in A, joined on B only if the keys match…. and only **after** the tables are joined is the where clause evaluated. It (essentially) says to keep the rows where *either* the IDs did not match *or* b.SomeString <> “ABC” (which, as per above, will exclude NULLs). Thus you end up with rows where the IDs did not match, **and** rows that did match where b.SomeSting was not ABC.

This stuff can be tricky to understand, hard to explain, and very hard to explain without sample data--which is me saying that you should poke at the your queries some until you get the sense of how this works.

Comment: I agree with the comments. I just wanted to try and explain it verbosely.

Comment: "If b.SomeString is null, as it will be if the key is not found, you get …and NULL is not equal to ABC ... and the row gets discarded from the returned set." this whole section is wrong. The non matched rows in the outer join are preserved and null extended after the match is evaluated.